# Meaning of "their very existence"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does "their very existence" means here?

> With **their very existence** dependent on the successful production of food, farmers had little, if any, time for removing stumps and stones.

Comment: It means they owed their lives to it. Without it, they were dead, i.e., non-existent.

Answer (score 3):

One of the definitions of [**very**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/very) (#6 at the link) is as a synonym for **actual**, which is how it is being used here.

This serves as an intensifier.  It's not their existence as farmers, but their **actual** existence as living people that was dependent on food production.  These farmers had to successfully produce food or die of starvation.

Answer (score 0):

It means their job is at risk – if the food production is not enough, they will become bankrupt